# Using outer query in inner query

Tags: sql, oracle

I don't understand what is the mistake here why it is not working (Oracle DB)

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/binary-search-tree-1/problem?isFullScreen=true

This is a question of hackerrank

```
SELECT N, 
(case
 when P IS NULL then 'Root'
 else
    when (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM BST WHERE P=B.N) > 0 then 'Inner'
    else 'Leaf'
    end
 end ))
 FROM BST AS B ORDER BY N;
```

First I thought that outer query is used in inner query so it won't work. But if it is working for MySQL then it should work for Oracle also.

This below code is for MySQL and it was working

```
SELECT N, IF(P IS NULL,'Root',IF((SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM BST WHERE P=B.N)>0,'Inner','Leaf')) 
FROM BST AS B ORDER BY N;
```

Comment: To your specific question, why doesn't your code work: You have a nested `case` expression. That is not necessary (as Barbaros Ozhan has shown), but if you do use a nested `case` expression (which is not wrong, it's just unnecessary) as you do, you are missing the keyword **`case`** in the inner expression - right before `when (SELECT COUNT.....` (As B.O. also said, you have an invalid use of `as` later in the query.)

Comment: You are saying that `case` is not necessary, can you tell me what is the simplified version of this query. Though Barbaroz Ozhan has given a great solution. I just want to know if you have another approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle doesn't support `as` for table aliases.  However, I would recommend writing this as:

```
select b.N, 
       (case when b.P IS NULL
             then 'Root'
             when exists (select 1 from bst b2 where b2.p = b.n) 
             then 'Inner'
             else 'Leaf'
        end)
from BST B
order by N;
```

This is standard SQL and should work in both Oracle and MySQL.

Notes:

- `CASE` expressions do not need to be nested.  They can have multiple `WHEN` clauses.
- In a query with multiple table references, *qualify* all column references.
- `exists` is faster than `count(*)` because it can stop at the first match.
- Aliasing tables through `AS` keyword is not allowed in Oracle DB

Comment: @harshalgarg . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?